# I'm Back in Black

Tags: movies

I have worn black for pretty much the entirety of my adult life.
I was 'killed' by something within me.
When I came back from the 'dead' I was wearing black.
I wore black for the rest of my life.

Who am I?

> To relieve some ambiguity, I only actually die once.

Comment: What we usually do is we post the puzzle without any hints first, then if no one gets it after a while you edit the post to add more. I think this has too much information...

Comment: Well, I thought that leaving it as is was a little to vauge.  I'll comment them out for now.

Comment: \*dusts off fingers\* there, Hints gone.

Comment: I think the in-puzzle hint comment could also go, and the "relieve" part could either be left out or put in spoilers.  Even the quotes might be a bit much. You underestimate the skills of some people here. ;) Even if not, we like to take a bit of time to think about these things.  Try a `lateral-thinking` tag if ambiguity is a part of the puzzle.

Comment: OK, I'll make those changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're

> Anakin Skywalker / Darth Vader

I have worn black for pretty much the entirety of my adult life.
+ I wore black for the rest of my life.

> Obviously...

I was 'killed' by something within me.

> Anakin was overcome by the dark side

When I came back from the 'dead' I was wearing black.

> "No. I am your father."

Comment: Yep.  Nice work.  Now just to wait until the timer expires so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess

> The Doctor? from Doctor Who? he dies, but revives all the time, just a wild guess.

Comment: Good guess, but no.

Comment: I thought not. oh well.

Comment: There, see edit to question for some help.